# Modal form not rendering on click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, modal-dialog

**Goal**

I am currently trying to create a new store via a modal.

**Issues**

- I am encountering an issue whereby my modal containing a form is not showing up when I click the button. *~ The new.js.erb file is reached, as I am able to render a flash message (instead of a form).~*
- Another issue is that I am currently using `<%= simple_form_for (Store.new) do |f|%>` instead of `<%= simple_form_for (@store) do |f|%>`. When I use the latter I get an error message: `` undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass ``
- **Update** After implementing Chandra's solution (see Answer below), my  tag lightens up in my browser when I click the button, therefore, I also attached my views/layouts/application.html.erb file.

**Code**

views/stores/index.html.erb

```
<%= render "partials/show_panel_stores_overview"%>
```

views/partials/show_panel_stores_overview.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'New store', new_store_path, remote: true %>
```

views/stores/new.js.erb

```
var form = $("<%= j(render 'form') %>");
var wrapper = $('<div>').attr('id', 'new-store-form').append(form);
$('body').append(wrapper);
```

views/stores/_form

```
<%= simple_form_for (Store.new) do |f|%>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.button :submit%>
```

store controller

```
def new
    @store = current_user.store.build
    @store.age_tables.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url, alert: 'Page not accessible' }
      format.js
    end
    authorize @store

  end

  def create
    @store = current_user.stores.create(store_params)
    authorize @store
    if @store.save
      redirect_to stores_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

views/layouts.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>TODO</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %> <!-- Uncomment if you import CSS in app/javascript/packs/application.js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'shared/flashes' %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code seems to be correct

there is one fix needs to be done at

views/stores/new.js.erb

```
var form = $('<%= j(render 'form') %>');
```

Replace this with

```
var form = $("<%= j(render 'form') %>");
```

Follow this link for example code to render partials , Ajax

https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy

Comment: Thank you Chandra. I tried implementing your solution, but the link still doesn't seem to work. However, the <head> tag lightens up in my browser (progress!;)), which might indicate the problem lies there. I will update my question with my head tags.

Comment: Update, the form rendered at the bottom of the page instead of within the supposed div. Your solution worked. Thank you so much!